# Communicating to ADFS using endpoint IP or Machine Name

Tags: token, claims-based-identity, endpoint, adfs3.0

I am able to communicate to ADFS server and authenticate users successfully. I have a question regarding the endpoint address.

My Question:

When communicating to ADFS , can I provide domain name in the place of address.

```
https://address/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed
```

when I try to enter domain name channel cannot be created. I want to know if I am missing any setting in my server DNS.

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate you go to:

https://xxx/adfs/ls

You need the same for:

https://xxx/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed

Comment: I am using  'https://xxx/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed' for authentication am I doing it wrong.It seems to work in my case. 
My question was 
what should XXXX be ( IP Address or Machine name).IP Address worked fine. I want to know if machine name should also work.

Comment: It should be the Federation Service Name.